# How do I prevent interpolation between values where there are more than 2 missing rows of data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to write a conditional statement inside mutate_at() so that approx() does not interpolate between values where there are more than 2 missing rows of data.

Here are the data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = 1:10, 
  var1 = c(10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 15), 
  var2 = c( 1, NA,  3,  6, NA, NA, NA, 10,  9,  8), 
  var3 = c(10, NA, NA, 13, 14, 16, NA, 18, 19, 20)
)
```

The is the chunk of code I would like to adapt such that it does NOT interpolate where there are more than 2 NAs between values (i.e., rows 5-7 in the var2 column should remain NA and all other NAs should be interpolated values.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_int <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(var2, var3)),
            funs(approx(time, ., time, rule = 1, method = "linear")[["y"]]))
```

Comment: Is the time step always 1? Are you just filling in missing values with the average of the surrounding values?

Comment: @MrFlick, no, the time step is not always one. This is a simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Create a function, `consecutiveNA`, that can identify the consecutive `NA` in a vector based on a threshold (specified by the argument `len`).

```
consecutiveNA <- function(x, len = 2){
  rl <- rle(is.na(x))
  logi <- rl$lengths >= len & rl$values
  rl$values <- logi
  inver <- inverse.rle(rl)
  return(inver)
}
```

Step 2: Apply the `approx` function to target columns (as you did).

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_int <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(var2, var3)),
            funs(approx(time, ., time, rule = 1, method = "linear")[["y"]]))
```

Step 3: Apply the `consecutiveNA` function to all columns in `dat` and convert the result to a matrix.

```
m_NA <- map(dat, consecutiveNA, len = 2) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Step 4: Based on `m_NA` to replace those `TRUE` with `NA` in `dat_int`, and then the work is done. You can change `len` to `3` or other numbers to see if it works.

```
dat_int[m_NA] <- NA

dat_int
#    time var1 var2 var3
# 1     1   10    1   10
# 2     2   10    2   NA
# 3     3   10    3   NA
# 4     4   12    6   13
# 5     5   12   NA   14
# 6     6   12   NA   16
# 7     7   15   NA   17
# 8     8   15   10   18
# 9     9   15    9   19
# 10   10   15    8   20
```

Comment: The above was a simplified example. My actual dataset has a column structure more like id1, id2, timestamp, var1, var2, var3 (i.e., there are important columns before the timestamp column). When I apply the code above I get the error 'Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, m_NA, value = NA) : unsupported matrix index in replacement` when running the last line of code `dat_int[m_NA] <- NA`. I think this is because of the additional non-numeric columns. Is there a simple way to adjust your code to deal with this? Or should I ask a new question on SO?

Comment: @DKincaid I don't have much time to study your question today. How about you post a new question with reproducible examples and let others take a look? I might look it later this week.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!