# How do I prevent interpolation between values where there are more than X number of missing rows of data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to interpolate missing data, but skip scenarios where there are more than X number (e.g., 3) missing rows of data. I have code below, but the final step does not work.

I previously posted a question and got a great answer ([How do I prevent interpolation between values where there are more than 2 missing rows of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599319/how-do-i-prevent-interpolation-between-values-where-there-are-more-than-2-missin/55603949?noredirect=1#comment98070872_55603949)). However, I oversimplified the example dataframe, and now when I try to run the code, I get this error in the final step:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, m_NA, value = NA) : unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

Is there a simple way to adjust the code below to deal with this? Or is there a better solution?

Here is a subset of my data:

```
alldata <- structure(list(q_cms = c(0.157, 0.154, 0.154, 0.151, 0.144, 0.151, 
0.151, 0.154, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.157, 0.144, NA), site = c("Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", 
"Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", 
"Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", 
"Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade", "Wade"), r_timestamp = structure(c(1479691800, 
1479692700, 1479693600, 1479694500, 1479695400, 1479696300, 1479697200, 
1479698100, 1479698160, 1479698220, 1479698280, 1479698340, 1479698400, 
1479698460, 1479698520, 1479698580, 1479698640, 1479698700, 1479698760, 
1479698820, 1479698880, 1479698940, 1479699000, 1479699900, 1479699960
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Etc/GMT-4"), NO3_mgNL = c(0.0351, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0316, 0.0309, 0.0309, 0.03, 0.029, 
0.0297, 0.0278, 0.0278, 0.0304, 0.0292, 0.0267, 0.0282, 0.0293, 
0.0313, 0.0306, NA, 0.0311), DOC_mgL = c(1.854, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.85, 1.843, 1.836, 1.822, 1.802, 1.836, 1.797, 1.808, 
1.817, 1.815, 1.813, 1.813, 1.824, 1.826, 1.82, NA, 1.831)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

And here is the code I am trying to execute. In this example, I am trying to skip interpolation where there are 3 or more consecutive missing rows of data:

Packages required:

```
library('tidyverse')
library('lubridate')
```

Step 1: Create a function, consecutiveNA, that can identify the consecutive NA in a vector based on a threshold (specified by the argument len):

```
consecutiveNA <- function(x, len = 3){
  rl <- rle(is.na(x))
  logi <- rl$lengths >= len & rl$values
  rl$values <- logi
  inver <- inverse.rle(rl)
  return(inver)
}
```

Step 2: Apply the approx function to target columns (interpolate NAs using linear interpolation):

```
alldata_int <- alldata %>%
  arrange(site, r_timestamp) %>%
  group_by(site, year(r_timestamp)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(NO3_mgNL, DOC_mgL)),
            funs(approx(r_timestamp, ., r_timestamp, rule=1, method="linear")[["y"]]))
```

Step 3: Apply the consecutiveNA function to all columns in alldata and convert the result to a matrix:

```
m_NA <- map(alldata, consecutiveNA, len = 3) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Step 4: Based on m_NA to replace those TRUE with NA in alldata_int, and then the work is done:

```
alldata_int[m_NA] <- NA
```

When I run Step 4, I get this error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, m_NA, value = NA) : unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

I think this is because of the additional non-numeric columns to the left of the timestamp column. Is there a simple way to adjust this code to deal with this? Or a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alldata_int` has one extra column, `year(r_timestamp)`, due to `group_by`. You have to remove that column to make `alldata_int` and `m_NA` have the same dimension. The following works for me.

By the way, `year` is probably from the `lubridate` package. It is better to provide where the function comes from.

```
alldata_int <- alldata %>%
  arrange(site, r_timestamp) %>%
  group_by(site, year(r_timestamp)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(NO3_mgNL, DOC_mgL)),
            funs(approx(r_timestamp, ., r_timestamp, rule=1, method="linear")[["y"]])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-`year(r_timestamp)`)

alldata_int[m_NA] <- NA
```

Answer (score 3):

`na.approx` in the zoo package has a `maxgap` argument:

```
library(zoo)

ok <- sapply(alldata, is.numeric)
replace(alldata, ok, lapply(alldata[ok], na.approx, maxgap = 2, na.rm = FALSE))
```